# Wordpress - Verify Identification before purchase

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a e-commerce website via wordpress. One feature I would like to implement is when a user logs into the portal, their account is unable to make any purchases until they have verified their ID. Once they upload their ID and we verify their account, they can make purchases on our shop.

Any ideas on how this could be done? I was playing around with it for a day now but can't seem to figure it out. I am using the WooCommerce plugin for my site and a custom theme. The wordpress theme I am using is called FeaturedLite.

Hoping I can get some help with this,  been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea how to implement this feature. Currently users can log in -> purchase items. I want them to not be able to purchase anything until their ID has been verified. I am also not sure how to even add a section for ID verification. I have tried to follow this tutorial https://www.shift8web.ca/2018/06/how-to-implement-a-government-id-verification-system-with-woocommerce-and-wordpress/ but i get a ton of syntax errors everywhere. I am not sure if this tutorial is outdated or just incorrect.